# How to identify which internal urls are ads using webscraping?

Tags: web-scraping

I wanted to create a Chrome extension that records a history of ads that have shown up in your browsing. I'm having trouble knowing where to start. I know that webscraping with things like beautiful soup can give you the urls of a page. How do you know which links are from advertisements? (products like AdSense allow you to find relevant information on your own website, but I wanted to create an ad history for the user)

On a level higher, how can you categorize these ads into similar topics (like gaming, music, etc)(does this require machine learning?)

Comment: It is important to separate two things.
Beautiful Soup is Python library. You cannot code Python in Chrome.
It is possible that Chrome calls a server that has Beautiful Soup running, but this starts to be complicated.

I would suggest starting using Beautiful Soup on its own. And when you get comfortable start researching Chrome extension building.

Also, the second part of question requires a separate QnA thread. But to be brief, machine learning could be useful. have a look at https://scikit-learn.org which is a perfect library to when learning ML.

Comment: I wish identifying advertisements would be as easy as if ads had html tags. How do you identify an ad on the webpage? Do you just have to cross-check the url to see if it matches a url base for known ads, if there even is one?

Comment: Ads are presented in webpages in many different ways.
You could be identifying add based on its URL, if you know it. Some ads definitely have patterns.
You could start by collecting samples of different pages (copy HTML) and looking into what they have in common.